# How to detect events for button appended with ActionCable?

Tags: coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I have created an ActionCable channel using `rails generate channel conversation speak`, then added something like the below code at the end of conversation.coffe:

```
$ ->
  $("button").click (event) ->
    alert() 
App.conversation.speak("main", event.target.value)
```

This works as intended and creates a new comment, along with a button that will spawn new comments. The appended button does not fire the above code though. I am using a comment partial and it works only on refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I changed the code detection in my coffee to
`$(document).on 'click', '[data-attribute]', (event) ->`